# Jquery not working when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So I have my code setup to make a box fade out when scrolling down (which works) but then when I tell it to fade back in when you scroll up it does not work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $(".box").animate({'opacity':'1'}, 1000);
    }
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $(".box").animate({'opacity':'0'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://plnkr.co/edit/jVBPtZ9Jh4zxmOSGJG4a?p=preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop annimation , before start new annimate function use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

See below working fiddle : ( scroll down to see effects )

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $(".box").stop().animate({'opacity':'1'}, 1000);
    }
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $(".box").stop().animate({'opacity':'0'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>

<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p><p>some paragraph</p>
```